# Silex/Symfony app working, but not in Facebook

Tags: facebook, symfony, silex

I have a Silex + Twig app running just fine on Heroku when not iframed, 
but when iframed in Facebook, it throws an exception.

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException: No route found for "POST /": Method Not
>   Allowed (Allow: GET)

Is there any particular way that Silex should handle any requests through Facebook?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your app is loaded inside facebook (in an iframe), the very first request is POST, not GET. Your route is defined as get-only. Change it to `->method()` (or even `->post()`, but I recommend method), and it'll work.

Comment: I changed `$app->get('/', function() use($app, $page) { 
    return $app['twig']->render('page.html', $page);
}); ` to `$app->match('/', function() use($app, $page) { 
    return $app['twig']->render('page.html.twig', $page);
})->method('POST|GET');` and it works fine, thanks very much.